# A student has to answer 8 out of 10 questions in an examination. How many choices does the student have if the first 3 questions must be answered?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Question:A student has to answer 8 out of 10 questions in an examination. How many choices does the student have if the first 3 questions must be answered?

The way I think of to solve this question is 10C3+7C3
Am I correct?

Comment: No.  After the first three, how many questions are left?  How many of them must be answered?

Comment: the question doesnt specific it very clear, but I suppose the student must answer 8 questions from 10 questions given. So after the first three, there will still have 5 out of 7 the student has to answer

Comment: Yes, that is correct.  Now how many ways to choose those?

Comment: Now I get it ! Thanks for the guidance!

Answer (score 1):

How many ways are there to choose the $2$ questions that *aren't* answered?  Since the first $3$ questions must be answered, there are $\binom 72 =21$ choices for the $2$ questions that aren't answered, so there are $21$ ways to choose $8$ of the $10$ questions if your choice is required to include the first $3$ questions.

Another way to get the same answer is to realize that you have no options among the first $3$ questions (you're given that they must be answered), so you're really trying to determine how many ways there are to choose $5$ of the remaining $7$ questions.  That number is $\binom 75 = \binom{7}{7-5} = \binom 72 = 21$ choices.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation!

Comment: My pleasure.  If you find an answer helpful, upvotes and acceptances are always appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The first three questions must be answered so there is no choices there.

The other five questions must be picked from the remaining seven problems.

Now you can figure out the correct answer.

Comment: Ya, I figured out ady, thanks!